# How to handle window manager in uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I was trying to catch a text from window manager in Android.

Description: 
I have an application which is blocked,  once this application is blocked from server it will display a window manager top of it stating "Application is blocked kindly contact your admin", I want to catch one of the text in this window manager and do validation!. When I focus on the window manager, I am able to see the blocked application attributes (class or package or id) rather than showing the window manager tags. [image]

Comment: can any give me steps how to catch  window manager attributes using uiautoamtor